# Unable to email using php when add context type

Tags: php

When I use headers like this, I cant receive the email that I send to myself

```
 $headers = "From: 123@example.com \r\n";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";  
 $headers .= "'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();";
```

but when I use this header just like this:

```
$headers = "From: 123@example.com \r\n";
```

I can receive the email that I send to myself.
Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it?

Comment: *From:* must be the email adress the smtp account is from

Comment: but it works when i use the header just with the "From: 123@example.com \r\n"

Comment: thank you for pointing out the email address should be the stmp account. I can receive the email now but still wondering why header like this still work : "From: 123@example.com \r\n"

Comment: Might be because when you use a single header - you add the \r\n at the end. When using multiple headers, however - the last \r\n is missing in your code. Not sure if this is the problem, but it might be.